# PyCharm Unix-like Shell, but Python from Windows, not Cygwin

Tags: python, pycharm, cygwin

I am new to PyCharm on Windows. I used it since years on Linux.

I would like to have unix-like shell in PyCharm on Windows, too.

If I follow these [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-tools-terminal.html), then I have nice bash shell. BUT it is cygwin. If I type "python", then I get Python from cygwin :-(

Up to now I use this: `"C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe" --login -i`

That's not what I want.

How can I get a unix-like shell and get Python from the virtualenv of PyCharm?

Here you can see which python version gets used:

```
foo@win7 /cygdrive/c/Users/foo/PycharmProjects/bar
$ python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Oct 31 2017, 21:12:13)
[GCC 6.4.0] on cygwin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring an alternative python interpreter in you PyCharm settings : see
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: I know this way to configure the interpreter. But in this case cygwin comes first and the python config does not get used. I updated the question to make this more clear.